# Increment a variable in InstallAware

Tags: variables, installation, installaware

I've recently used InstallAware to  convert  my  WISE project.  It was not a great a success as many parts of the wise scripts were missing. Anyway, I was wondering if there is any option in InstallAware to increment a variable (to be used in a while loop). In WISE we could do so by setting the variable's operation as Increment.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easly accomplish to your request with the following code fragment in your InstallAware script:

```
Set Variable MYVAR to 0

while Variable MYVAR not Greater Than (Version) 9 loop

  MYVAR = $MYVAR$ + 1

wend
```

I may suggest to have also a look to "Mathematics" embedded command.

Hope this helps you.